# How to enable copy paste from between host machine and virtual machine in vmware, virtual machine is ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am trying to copy and paste from my pc to the vm but i cant.

I also enable copy and paste but i still can't copy and paste from my pc to the vm. My pc runs windows 8.1 my vm has fedora.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to install **VMware Tools** on your vm:

To install VMware Tools in most VMware products:

Power on the virtual machine.

Log in to the virtual machine using an account with Administrator or root privileges.

Wait for the desktop to load and be ready.

Click Install/Upgrade VMware Tools. There are two places to find this option:

- Right-click on the running virtual machine object and choose
  Install/Upgrade VMware Tools.
- Right-click on the running virtual
  machine object and click Open Console. In the Console menu click VM
  and click Install/Upgrade VMware Tools.

  Note: In ESX/ESXi 4.x, navigate to VM > Guest > Install/Upgrade
  VMware Tools. In Workstation, navigate to VM > Install/Upgrade VMware
  Tools.

[...]

Source: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014294

Comment: This doesn't work in my case.

Comment: If anyone has already tools installed on Linux and still isn't able to copy/paste, please make sure you have **open-vm-tools-desktop** package installed as this seems to be a key package here. You can install it on Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop`

Comment: Make sure `/usr/bin/vmtoolsd -n vmusr` process is running (see [Start VMWare process manually](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-C6066CB0-33EA-4652-9AB3-0324080DCBEE.html)). Execute `/usr/bin/vmware-user` to enable copy and paste.

Comment: This problem occurs also when VMWAreTools IS installed.

Comment: Your tip worked, @GregWozniak. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me. Might want to try editing virtual machine settings:

[image: Click on Edit virtual machine settings]

[image: Switch to Always Enabled in Options, Shared Folders]

Comment: that did the trick for me - already had the VMTools installed...

Comment: Other solutions failed, but this, and then reboot, helped! Lubuntu i386 guest.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a small hint that I hope might be useful to other poor saps that experienced the same issue as I did.

My Setup:
Host: Windows 7 Enterprise - build 7601 SP 1
VM: VMware® Workstation 12 Player  12.1.1 build-3770994  (free)
Guest: Fedora release 23

I naively failed to install *open-vm-tools-desktop*.  I say naively because I had no idea such a thing existed, nor do I understand why instructions to install *open-vm-tools* do not (or at least where I read them, do not) include mentions of this package.

Installing open-vm-tools on its own appears to be nearly useless - the *desktop* package makes the copy and paste function - probably the single most important function of VMTools - work.

So, there you go.  Install open-vm-tools-desktop, and copy-paste *should* work

Comment: That did it for me. I had uploaded my VM onto an ESXi host, and my copy-paste stopped working. I had installed open-vm-tools but not open-vm-tools-desktop! I was about to set up an rdp connection after trying everything under the sun.

Comment: Thanks for this, I looked high and low for what I was missing and the desktop was the key, but you don't find this posted anywhere else.

Answer (score 7):

If your VM already came with VMware Tools pre-installed, but this still isn't working for you--or if you install and still no luck--make sure you run Workstation or Player as Administrator. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution I started using after being fed up with the copy and paste issue:

1. Download MRemote (for pc). this is an alternative to remote desktop manager. You can use remote desktop manager if you like.
2. Change the VMNet settings to NAT or add another VMNet and set it to NAT.
3. Configure the vm ip address with an ip in the same network as you host machine. if you want to keep networks separated use a second vmnet and set it's ip address in the same network as the host. that's what I use.
4. Enable RDP connections on the guest (I only use windows guests)
5. Create a batch file with this command. add your guest machines:

vmrun start D:\VM\MySuperVM1\vm1.vmx nogui
vmrun start D:\VM\MySuperVM2\vm2.vmx nogui

save the file to startmyvms.cmd

create another batch file and add your vms

vmrun stop D:\VM\MySuperVM1\vm1.vmx nogui
vmrun stop D:\VM\MySuperVM2\vm2.vmx nogui

save the file to stopmyvms.cmd

6. Open Mremote go to tools => External tools
   Add external tool => filename will be the startmyvms.cmd file
   Add external tool => filename will be the stopmyvms.cmd file
   So to start working with your vms:
7. Create you connections to your VMs in mremote

Now to work with your vm 
1. You open mremote
2. You go to tools => external tools
3. You click the startmyvms tool
when you're done 
1. You go to tools => external tools
2. You click the stopmyvms external tool

you could add the vmrun start on the connection setting => external tool before connection
and add the vmrun stop in the connection settings => external tool after

Voilà !

Answer (score -3):

Are you talking about drag and drop, when you say copy and paste?
If yes, you can also use Rightclick on object on your main computer and click copy. And then you go into the Virtual Machine and Rightclick the position where you want the file to get copied to.

If this doesn't work use the method KaiserM11 explained and get yourselfe VMware Tools like in this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McjwI_6BKZY

Hope my answer was helpfull to you and happy coding :D

Answer (score -4):

the mremote option offers more automation and almost replicates the vmware workstation graphical experience plus major benefits: 
NO DPI (guest resolution) hassle 
no copy pose hassle
Automation = starting vms and suspending them automatically
plus more if you look deeper

Answer (score -7):

You need to install some packages such as Unlocker, GuestOSx, etc.