# Vmware 12: Can't copy paste between Host and Virtual computer

Tags: ubuntu, window, vmware

I everyone.

I have a trouble with VMWare Virtual. I used Lubuntu LXDE 15.10. I can't copy and paste although I have completed install VMware-tools. I can resize windows and enable shared folder but I can't copy and paste text from host to VM computer.
I have tried:

1: Reinstall VMWare tool

2: Follow Exactly step by step from this answer: [Copy and paste in VMWare doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647900/copy-and-paste-in-vmware-doesnt-work)

but those solutions doesn't work,

Does anyone get a tip?

Thank's

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently.
On my Debian-based Linux Guest System, I've learned, that VMware Tools are no longer recommended for Linux. Instead, I had to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Please note, that open-vm-tools alone will i.e. adjust display size, but (at least in my case) was not able to provide copy-paste-functionality, as it is x-server-related. This was then however included in open-vm-tools-desktop. It depends on you linux distribution, if there are more than one package to install.

Source:
https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools

> "Will there be continued support for VMware Tools and OSP?
>
> VMware Tools will continue to be available under a commercial license.
>   It is recommended that open-vm-tools be used for the Linux
>   distributions where open-vm-tools is available. VMware will not
>   provide OSPs for operating systems where open-vm-tools is available."